# Combining multiple template classes to one class using typedef

Tags: c++, templates, macros, typedef

I have the following piece of code. 
Let us have the function declaration and implementation
seperate.

```
#include <iostream> 

class Y1 {}; 
class Y2 {}; 

template <class T1, class T2> 
class A
{   
    public:
        explicit A();
        void foo() const;
        int bar() const;
};  

template <class T1, class T2> 
A<T1, T2>::A() {}

template <class T1, class T2> 
void A<T1, T2>::foo() const {}

template <class T1, class T2> 
int A<T1, T2>::bar() const {}

int main() {
    A<Y1, Y2> a;
    a.foo();


    A<Y1, Y2> *a2 = new A<Y1, Y2>();
    a2->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

It is a pain every time writing

```
template <class T1, class T2>
```

for every object declaration and function declaration.

Can someone help with a macro or typedef to shorten the 
template parameters description.

Comment: You can define the member functions inline.

Comment: I understand. But let us keep the structure and implementation seperate.

Comment: As @juanchopanza said ... they most likely have to be at the same place as the class definition anyway, due to being templates.

Comment: I'd say that for templates, it is common *not* to separate them, as you gain very little from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my own code I also separate the declaration from the implementation.  Sometimes I just need the code to know that there exists a template, more often I want to make it very easy to see what the interfaces are.

I have solved this tedious typing with macros.  However, the solution is complicated.

In case your return type does not have a comma (that is, excluding cases such as `std::unordered_map<int, std::string>`) here's a simple utility macro:

```
#define TEMPLATE2(returnType, className, type1, type2) \
   template<typename type1, typename type2> returnType className<type1, type2>::
```

You can use it like this:

```
TEMPLATE2(, A, T1, T2)::A() { ... }
```

and

```
TEMPLATE2(int, A, T1, T2)::bar() const { ... }
```

You could have `TEMPLATE1`, `TEMPLATE3` and so on for more and more template arguments.  However, you can also split this into two macros: one that generates the typelist, and one to generate the specialization.  I have done them, but believe me, not even I like it.  It is not lack of preprocessing skill, I can tell you there is no satisfactory way to avoid the verbiage.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it will be better to implement the functions in the class definition itself. Then, your problem disappears altogether.

If you must implement the functions outside, you can use something like the macro below for simple return types.:

```
#define A_FUNC(ret, name) \
template <class T1, class T2> \
ret A<T1, T2>::name

A_FUNC(void, foo)() const {}

A_FUNC(int, bar)()  const { return 0;}
```

However, for complex return types, that logic will break down. Say you have:

```
template <class T1, class T2> 
class A
{   
    public:
        explicit A() {}
        void foo() const;
        int bar() const;
        char const* (*)(int, int) bar2() const;
};
```

I don't know if there is a way to capture that return type as a macro argument.

Using

```
A_FUNC((char const* (*)(int, int)), bar2)()  const { return NULL;}
```

leads to all sorts of compiler errors.

Comment: +1 for the example returning a pointer to function, but -1 for recommending mixing the declarations with the definitions of the member functions.  There are very good reasons to separate them.  Number one, there are cases where you just need the declaration, even of a template; that's enough to for instance know the type of the member.  And more practically, the interfaces look cleaner without the implementation

Comment: @EdMaster, whether to implement the function inside the class definition or outside the class definition seems to be a matter of opinion. For simple functions, I would very rarely, if ever, implement the functions outside the class. For complex functions, implementing them outside the class definition makes sense.